# How to update screen dimensions in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have been trying to update my screen dimensions in react native so that the component resizes on-screen rotation with no vain. I have created my style in a separate file (Styles.js) and imported the styles in my login page like below:

**Styles.js**

```js
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import {
  scale,
  ScaledSheet
} from "react-native-size-matters";

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({

  scrollViewContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#E20030',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    padding: '50@s'
  },
  container2: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    flex: 1,
  },

  loginRect: {

    borderRadius: '30@s',
    marginTop: '20@s',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 0,
    marginLeft: '35@s',
    marginRight: '35@s',
    borderWidth: '1@s',
    borderRadius: '5@s',


    borderColor: '#dadae8',
  },
});
```

**Login.js**

```js
import React, { } from 'react';
import {
    Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import { mystyles, styles } from './Components/styles';

const LoginScreen = () => {


    return (
        <View style={mystyles.scrollViewContainer}>


            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 100 }}>

                <View style={mystyles.scrollViewContainer}>

                    <View style={mystyles.loginRect}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 45, marginTop: 20 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Username</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.input}
                            />

                        </View>

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 45, marginTop: 20 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Password</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.input}
                            />
                        </View>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>LOGIN</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>


                    </View>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </View>
    )
}



export default LoginScreen;
```

So I have tried using Dimensions onchange listener in my **Styles.js** but I get an error

> ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I created this function in the **Styles.js** file
m

```js
function getDimensions() {

  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    window,
    screen
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener(
      "change",
      ({
        window,
        screen
      }) => {
        setDimensions({
          window,
          screen
        });
        console.log(dimensions.window.height + " +++ " + dimensions.screen)
      }
    );
    //   return () => subscription?.remove();
  });
  return dimensions.window;
}
```

Is there any way I can update the component sizes once the screen has been rotated?

Comment: This `getDimensions` function needs to be a custom hook [1] (changing its name to `useDimensions` should fix it). The `useEffect` should also have an empty dependency array, as you only want it to be called on mount.


  [1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to detect rotation or changes in the size of the screen (split mode in tablets for example) without eventListeners.

```
import {  Dimensions } from "react-native";
...
useEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [Dimensions.get("screen").height, Dimensions.get("screen").width]);
```

Hope this help to anybody